Eq. (#) at the beginning of a sentence
As far as I know, Eq. (#) is a typically used short form of Equation (#) in scientific journal papers. I am wondering if this abbreviation can also be used at the beginning of a sentence. That is, can we start a sentence with Eq. (#)? As far as I know, abbreviations must not be used at the beginning of a sentence, but I am not sure if this convention applies to the case of 'Equation'.
Thank you.

I can find nothing about abbreviations at the beginning of sentences in the Chicago Manual of Style (CMOS). The CMOS (9.5) only states that numbers (and associated units of measure) should be spelled out at the beginning of a sentence, e.g.:

One hundred ten candidates were accepted.
or
In all, 110 candidates were accepted.

The CMOS recommends to rephrase sentences so that numbers do not appear at the beginning of sentences.
The Publication Manual of the American Psychological Association (APA, 6th, 4.30 = APA, 7th, 6.26) states:

Never begin a sentence with a lowercase abbreviation (e.g., lb) ... Begin a sentence with a capitalized abbreviation or acronym (e.g., U.S. or APA) ... only when necessary to avoid indirect and awkward writing.

So, apparently, according to both the CMOS and the APA you may use "Eq. (#)" at the beginning of a sentence – APA: if necessary. But note that according to the APA (7th, 6.25) you must not spell out an abbreviation after you have defined it:

After you define an abbreviation, use only the abbreviation; do not alternate between spelling out the term and abbreviating it.

The rules of specific journals may differ from this.
